# How Can I only Get the Search adsets with name in FB api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Marketing API.
I can get the adSets related to an account using

```
FB.api('accountId/adsets')
```

But i am looking for a option so that i can pass a string and FB returns only the adsets that starts with that string? Is there any functionality in FB api that does this?

Comment: No, there isn’t. That kind of filtering you have to do on your end.